# Combine one Byte[] to Single Array

Tags: c#, arrays, buffer, readblock

i do have an byte array included a range of numbers...

t Block and not the rest!

How can i have all block 4-8 in `Temp[]` ??

Comment: You mean you have 4 bytes which together make up an `int`?

Comment: yes i have 4Byte and in Temp also i need to have 4 Bytes but the method i used it only return me the 1th byte and skip the rest how can i return all 4 bytes in my Temp?

Comment: CMD suppose to be [493131] but now its only 49 the first Byte

Comment: which byte is the most significant the first or the last?

Comment: BlockCopy is Correct as i test already the only thing is this Block copy have to read 3 Bytes and store them in one Array Called Temp[]

Answer (score 2):

Elements 4-8 (or in reality index 3-7) is 5 bytes. Not 4.
You have the source offset and count mixed up:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(bResponse, 3, temp, 0, 5);
```

Now temp will contain `[23232]`.

If you want the last 4 bytes then use this:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(bResponse, 4, temp, 0, 4);
```

Now temp will contain `[3232]`.
To convert this to an int:

```
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
  Array.Reverse(temp);

int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(temp, 0);
```

**Edit:**  (After your comment that `[43323232]` actually is `{43, 32, 32, 32}`)

```
var firstByte = temp[0];   // This is 43
var secondByte = temp[1];  // This is 32
var thirdByte = temp[2];   // 32
var fourthByte = temp[3];  // 32
```

If you want to convert this to an int then the BitConverter example above still works.

Comment: This is not the Answer! This one its only to take 3 block from buffer how you want to assign this 3 in one Temp[]?

Comment: Each of this have to read individually and sort in Temp back to back with your method is nothing but only reading 4bytes. I have no problem for reading the problem is assigning this 4 in another Array i call Temp[]

Comment: @Artinos: You are wrong about the number of bytes read. If you read the MSDN page of [Buffer.BlockCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) you'll see that it is you who have mixed up the `source offset` and `count` parameters.

Comment: You are Right about the Number My bad in Typing ...However i still cannot Put put the 3 byte block into one block called Temp[]